# Custom Object Parameter Conversion and Parametarised Scenarios in jBehave

Tags: json, bdd, jbehave

I am having a problem for which I cannot find a solution anywhere in the jBehave documentation. I have a story like this:

```
Given We have a JSON {boo: <boo>, foo: <foo>}.
When We get this.
Then We shall assert.

Examples:
|boo|foo|
|3|4|
```

And a step like this:

```
@Given("We have a JSON {$obj}.")
    public void given(@Named("obj") final OwrObj obj) {
        // Some code...
    }
```

I also have a custom parameter converter which converts to OwrObj objects. My problem is that the converter gets a String input:

```
"{boo: <boo>, foo: <foo>}"
```

instead of:

```
"{boo: 3, foo: 4}".
```

In short, what is inside the curly brackets is seen as a parameter value.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish what I am trying to do. That is, get a custom object from a parametarised JSON structure in the story?

Comment: Would it suffice to pass the full json as a parameter value? I believe that jBehave collects the pattern parameter names from the step pattern before using those names to lookup the examples table for replacement. If that Is the case, this wont work since your step pattern parameter obj doesnt match your examples named parameters.